# How to configure WP Mail SMTP plugin for localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am struggle for 2 days with this problem.
I am going to send email from my localhost using WordPress.

I am using `wp_mail()` function so I decided to use WP Mail SMTP plugin.
But I have a problem while configuring it.

[image]

This is screen shot of my configuration.
When I try to send test email, it fails.

Anyone please help me

Comment: all the comments from SanchitGupta are absolutely right. I think the issue is different reason. What plugins are you using on your site?

Comment: Here is the list of plugins I am using. Advanced Custom Fields PRO, Ajax Load More, Amazon Web Services, Contact Form 7, Featured Post, Google Apps Login Premium, Image Regenerate & Select Crop, PHP Code Widget,  Postman SMTP, WP Mail SMTP, WP Offload S3 Lite, WP Super Cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the plugins list, I've noticed you are using Postman SMTP plugin, which causes conflict with the WP Mail SMTP plugin. If you disable that plugin, it will work correctly.

Comment: Wow!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!. It works perfectly. You've saved my 3 days. Thank you VERY MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with following SMTP setting for gmail to configure on localhost with your plugin  :

```
HOST : smtp.gmail.com
PORT : 587
USERNAME : Your_gmail_ID
PASSWORD : Your_gamil_Password
Encryption : TLS
```

**NOTE** : Make sure your gmail account must be `Allow less secure apps: ON`. You can turn on less secure apps for your account using [***THIS URL***](https://myaccount.google.com/security)

### **UPDATE**

As discussed please use following setting in your plugin :

**WP Mail SMTP Settings**

```
From Email : Your_gmail_EmailID 
From Name : Your_name 
Mailer : Send all WordPress emails via SMTP. 
Return Path : checked
```

After that Click on **Save Changes**

Now under **SMTP Options**

```
SMTP Host : smtp.gmail.com
SMTP Port : 587
Encryption : Use TLS encryption.
Authentication : Yes: Use SMTP authentication.
Username : Your_gmail_EmailID
Password : Your_gamil_EmailPassword
```

After that Click on **Save Changes**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160115/discussion-on-answer-by-sanchit-gupta-how-to-configure-wp-mail-smtp-plugin-for-l).

Answer (score 0):

install plugin wp mail smtp
then in general settings

From Email:your email
mailer: other smtp

SMTP Host:smtp.gmail.com
Encryption:ssl
port:456

SMTP Username: your gmail address
SMTP Password: your gmail password

**save settings**

after that test email by sending one to

Send To: email that you want to receive email on
and **make sure your SMTP Username(your gmail) account has turn on less secure apps**

hope i helped.